# How to acess object fields/properties from another object contained in that object efficiently

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to design a problem that is similar to this, I have an object that contains another objects as in the example below. I am trying to figure out a way to acess the first object properties from the second object without having to replicate properties unnecessarily between them which doesnt sound like a good programming practice.

For example:

```
class employee{
    String name;
    int age;
}
class company{
    String companyName;
    List<employee> employeeList;
}
```

My question is, given an employee object, how can I accesss the companyName that this employee works for? One solution is to add companyName to each employee object but that seems to be a redundant waste of memory as it is "guaranteed" that each employee works for only one company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it now you have a unidirectional dependency. In other words, `company` depends on `employee`. However, `employee` knows nothing about the `company` it belongs to.

You can simply add a `company` field to `employee` and every time you create an `employee` or add it to a `company`'s `employeeList`, remember to update both sides of the now bidirectional dependency.

---

Note that Java naming conventions state that type names should start with a capitalized letter.

Answer (score 1):

C++: You could give the employee a `company` pointer, passed as part of the `employee` constructor and access `companyName` through that.